# Request timeout with Facebook API on iOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api

I have a bunch of URL requests that are sent out in batch and then a 'catcher' class that recieves the results. I'm doing this through facebook's graph API SDK so I don't have control of the actual NSURL. My problem is that I don't trigger the next result protocol until all requests have come back, but sometimes, especially over 3G, they don't always come back (especially when you have a few hundred). What's a good way to 'give up' on a given request? The way the actual request works, for those who aren't familiar with the FB api, is you initialize a facebook object and then request data from it, and you specify a return delegate. So, for each individual request I have a returnDelegate (the catcher), which I can initialize specific to each request.

**UPDATE: Some code from FB-API**

```
- (FBRequest*)requestWithMethodName:(NSString *)methodName
                          andParams:(NSMutableDictionary *)params
                      andHttpMethod:(NSString *)httpMethod
                        andDelegate:(id <FBRequestDelegate>)delegate {
    NSString * fullURL = [kRestserverBaseURL stringByAppendingString:methodName];
    return [self openUrl:fullURL
                  params:params
              httpMethod:httpMethod
                delegate:delegate];
}

- (FBRequest*)openUrl:(NSString *)url
               params:(NSMutableDictionary *)params
           httpMethod:(NSString *)httpMethod
             delegate:(id<FBRequestDelegate>)delegate {

    [params setValue:@"json" forKey:@"format"];
    [params setValue:kSDK forKey:@"sdk"];
    [params setValue:kSDKVersion forKey:@"sdk_version"];
    if ([self isSessionValid]) {
        [params setValue:self.accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
    }

    [self extendAccessTokenIfNeeded];

    FBRequest* _request = [FBRequest getRequestWithParams:params
                                               httpMethod:httpMethod
                                                 delegate:delegate
                                               requestURL:url];
    [_requests addObject:_request];
    [_request addObserver:self forKeyPath:requestFinishedKeyPath options:0 context:finishedContext];
    [_request connect];
    return _request;
}

- (void)connect {

    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestLoading:)]) {
        [_delegate requestLoading:self];
    }

    NSString* url = [[self class] serializeURL:_url params:_params httpMethod:_httpMethod];
    NSMutableURLRequest* request =
    [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                        timeoutInterval:kTimeoutInterval];
    [request setValue:kUserAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];


    [request setHTTPMethod:self.httpMethod];
    if ([self.httpMethod isEqualToString: @"POST"]) {
        NSString* contentType = [NSString
                             stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", kStringBoundary];
        [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        [request setHTTPBody:[self generatePostBody]];
    }

    _connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    self.state = kFBRequestStateLoading;
    self.sessionDidExpire = NO;
}
```

Comment: What's the request class? Some code?

Comment: @noa just added some. Need help understanding it. Is there a hacky way of adding a literal timer for each request that sends a message to the delegate after it reaches a certain time?

Comment: Sure, I think NSTimer can do that. If you fire the requests at the same time, you could use one timer for all of them.

Comment: Naaaah I need to have a single timer for each request. The idea is that I'll ship out a bunch of requests (like 100) and whichever ones return within the allotted time are the ones I'd use. Will running so many threads get screwy?

Comment: Sorry to say I don't really know. If having 100 requests works, I'd think 100 requests + 100 timers would, too.

Comment: OK thanks thats probably perfect! (if you had answered that as an answer..I would have accepted it!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed above, you can *implement your own timeout* by instantiating an `NSTimer` which will signal a delegate object when a certain amount of time elapses.